# Voiceover should say as current date and current month in react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datepicker

I am using react modern calendar date picker module. I am trying to use aria-current attribute in the module to display as current date in accessibility. Anyone can able to help how to add aria-current attribute?